# Have we become over-reliant on cookies?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, cookies

Once I turned off cookies, Amazon.com & Google.com refuses to sign me in.  I am not able to log in into even Stackoverflow.com.  Is no one using URL rewriting nowadays?

What is the latest thought on cookies, URL rewriting and sessions in web communities?

Comment: I don't know what URL rewriting has to do with session management or authentication?

Comment: @Widor servlets support placing a token in the URL as an alternative to using session cookies, though most admins turn this off due to security concerns; it requires consistent use of `encodeURL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean to put the session id in the url, and then rewrite that url to hide it again?
It seems a cumbersome solution, and it will mean that all urls are indexed with a session id by search engines. Cookies make life easier and websites better (you can store other data in there too). Modern browsers should support cookies and javascript, because they play an important role in the implementation of modern day web experience.

If you need to support browsers without cookie support, you can, but you're practically alone nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

The latest thoughts are that cookies won ;-) very few people do url rewriting ... in truth, it's very easy to create a huge security hole by putting all the session info in the URL.

The web no longer works without cookies